# Polymer custom element property not accessible in nested template

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a custom element like below:

```dart
<polymer-element>
    <template if="{{primaryLoaded}}">
        <template repeat="{{pData in primaryData}}">
            <p>{{pData.propertyOne}}</p>
            <p>{{someClass.someOperation()}}</p>
            <template if="{{secodaryLoaded}}">
                <p>{{secondaryData.someProperty}}</p>
                <p>{{someClass.someOperation()}}</p>
            </template>
        </template>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

and a corresponding dart file:

```dart
class CustomElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin
{
    @observable bool primaryLoaded = false;
    @observable bool secondaryLoaded = false;
    @observable var primaryData;
    @observable var secondaryData;
    @observable var someClass;

    void created()
    {
        primaryData = toObservable(new List<var>());
        secondaryData = toObservable(new List<var>());
    }

    void inserted()
    {
        someClass = new SomeClass();
        loadPrimaryData().then((pData) {
            primaryData = pData;
            primaryLoaded = true;
            loadSecondaryData().then((sData) {
                secondaryData = sData;
                secondaryLoaded = true;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for the `primaryData`. Its properties get printed and the call to `someOperation()` on `someClass` prints its data correctly.

The problem is in the nested template. Nothing under the `<template if="{{secondaryLoaded}}">` gets displayed. Even the call to `someClass.someOperation()` fails to display anything.

Is there a problem with scope here? It looks like the outer template can reference the properties defined in the dart file without problem but the nested template can't.

I read about setting variables as globals in the template by setting a custom binding delegate [here](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions). However, I can't set the bindingDelegate in my custom element as `isTemplate` returns false.

Is there any other way of setting a global variable in a custom template? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. You can star this issue to be notified of changes:

> > https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12742

The only thing you can do for now is to turn nested templates into other polymer elements or figure out a way so the template isn't nested.

In your case, instead of using `if="primaryLoaded"` you could just set `primaryData = null` and the template shoud not display anything until `primaryData` is set, assuming `primaryData` is `@observable`.

Comment: I got it working by removing the inner template. As you said it does not print errors or crash when the Polymer Expression is null. I don't think this was the case with Web UI which is why the template was there in the first place. Thanks :-)